# Form Inside IFrame Submitting to Target _blank Fails in IE

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer, iframe

First, this issue only occurs in any version of IE and works correctly in Firefox and Chrome.

I have a form which is on a page inside an iframe.  I am submitting the form to a page on our other web site.  When the form page is on top (not in an iframe) all works fine.  If I place this same form in an iframe and submit the form, a new window opens as expected however none of my form values arrive at the target page.  This smells like an IE bug or security/permissions setting.  Again, it works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome.

I am seeing the issue whether I add target="_blank" to the form tag or I add it say via jQuery after the form loads.

Comment: You shouldn't use target="_blank" on forms.